# WinAPI: wait for IO completion on a file descriptor

Tags: python-3.x, winapi

I write a Python app that supports Linux and Windows, and I have a file object (that has a `fileno()` method returning a file descriptor), and I need to wait for IO completion on it.

In this particular case it's database connection (Postgresql), and I need to process notifications without a load on CPU (like it is described [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html#asynchronous-notifications)).

On Linux it's quite simple:

```
select.select([fd], [], [])
```

But I would like to be able to do something like that on Windows too, and I'm struggling to find the correct way to achieve it.

It looks like `WaitForSingleObject` function could be handy, but as far as I understand it does not accept file descriptors.

How could this possibly be resolved?

Comment: On Windows, you have to open the file using `CreateFile()` specifying the `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag, then you can create an `OVERLAPPED` struct holding a waitable event from `CreateEvent()` and pass that struct to read/write operations that support overlapped I/O, then you can wait on the event. See [Overlapped operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/devio/overlapped-operations) for more details. But, how you do all of that in Python, I have no clue.

Comment: Microsofts C implementation provides functions that can transform fd's into operating system handles (`_ofshandle` iirc). Does Python not have a similar thing?